# Run GruntJs task from php exec function

Tags: php, windows, gruntjs, wamp

I would like to perform some grunt task by running command from php exec function.

I've already:

- Install grunt globally: `npm -g install grunt-cli`
- Setup apache and windows to allow running CLI from php (I use
  wampserver)

I ran this script from php:

```
<?php
exec('grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile.js');`
```

And I found in apache log that `grunt command is not found` whereas I can run this command from CLI and grunt is in my env path.

So I've decided to create a batch file that contains that script and launch the batch instead of the grunt command directly.

```
<?php
exec ('gruntTask.bat'); // I know that it can execute script because I can 
                        // create folder if I put mkdir command in gruntTask.bat`
```

**gruntTask.bat** contains:

```
grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile.js
```

But why it couldn't execute this script? Have I missed something?

Need helps guys,

Regards,